# Resource Leak opengl/win32

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl

Hello I've recently started learning win32/opengl and I managed to write a function that displays a multi colored cube within a window. My problem is there is a resource leak but I'm stumped and not sure what exactly I'm forgetting to delete.

NOTE I have narrowed it down to be within this function

```
void display() 
{
    g.hglrc = wglCreateContext(g.hdc);
    wglMakeCurrent(g.hdc, g.hglrc);

    // make the color a white hue  
    glClearColor(1.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F);

    //  Clear screen and Z-buffer
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Reset transformations
    glLoadIdentity();

    // Rotate when user changes rotate_x and rotate_y
    glRotatef(rotate_x, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glRotatef(rotate_y, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

    //Multi-colored side - FRONT
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);     glVertex3f(0.5, -0.5, -0.5);      // P1 is red
    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);     glVertex3f(0.5, 0.5, -0.5);      // P2 is green
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);     glVertex3f(-0.5, 0.5, -0.5);      // P3 is blue
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 1.0);     glVertex3f(-0.5, -0.5, -0.5);      // P4 is purple
    glEnd();

    // White side - BACK
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glVertex3f(0.5, -0.5, 0.5);
    glVertex3f(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
    glVertex3f(-0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
    glVertex3f(-0.5, -0.5, 0.5);
    glEnd();

    // Purple side - RIGHT
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glVertex3f(0.5, -0.5, -0.5);
    glVertex3f(0.5, 0.5, -0.5);
    glVertex3f(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
    glVertex3f(0.5, -0.5, 0.5);
    glEnd();

    // Green side - LEFT
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(-0.5, -0.5, 0.5);
    glVertex3f(-0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
    glVertex3f(-0.5, 0.5, -0.5);
    glVertex3f(-0.5, -0.5, -0.5);
    glEnd();

    // Blue side - TOP
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glVertex3f(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
    glVertex3f(0.5, 0.5, -0.5);
    glVertex3f(-0.5, 0.5, -0.5);
    glVertex3f(-0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
    glEnd();

    // Red side - BOTTOM
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(0.5, -0.5, -0.5);
    glVertex3f(0.5, -0.5, 0.5);
    glVertex3f(-0.5, -0.5, 0.5);
    glVertex3f(-0.5, -0.5, -0.5);
    glEnd();

    wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);

    SwapBuffers(g.hdc);
    ReleaseDC(g.hwnd, g.hdc);
    wglDeleteContext(g.hglrc);
}
```

Comment: What makes you think that there is a "resource leak"?

Comment: If I leave the program running with the display call the ram usage easily goes up to 100s of mb and continues to grow. If I remove the call to this function the usage stays constant at around 27-28mbs regardless of how long it is running. So I assume that this is the result of a resource leak since I don't see anything else that would cause such behavior.

Comment: Comment out the contents of the function, verify the problem is gone, then gradually uncomment a line/section at a time until the problem comes back.

Comment: Please stop changing the question.

Comment: A better way to work when you suspect a leak is to use a tool called [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html). It will narrow down to a specific call. Pasting the output of that tool to an SO question will likely get a faster answer.

Comment: @AndrewC. Valgrind currently does not support Windows. There are equivalents, though; I wouldn't be able to suggest one.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> g.hglrc = wglCreateContext(g.hdc);
> ```

Don't do that.

You don't create a rendering context every time you need to redraw the screen. You create it *once*; it should only go away when your *window* goes away.

Now, that doesn't necessarily justify why creating and destroying a rendering context would leave resources lying around. But that's irrelevant; you shouldn't do it because of *performance*. Rendering context creation and destruction is not a fast process, nor is it intended to be.

Comment: You're right there is a significant performance boost when I take it out of the function but the resource leak persists.

Comment: Not just that line you pointed out, but all the `wgl` calls in a display loop, especially the other win32 lines near the bottom that make current context null and release the DC will no doubt cause some resource thrash too.